# What's wrong with click handling of my buttons inside a reusable layout?

Tags: android, android-activity, reusability

I have a reusable layout with a back button. I want to handle click event of my back button from BaseActivity. I set the onClick of the button to "headerClickHandler" and I have a method with this name in BaseActivity but When I click the button, an error says there is no headerClickHandler. What's wrong?
this is my Header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtHeading"
        android:text="@string/general_title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:background="@color/red_hover"
        android:text="@string/return_value"
        android:onClick="headerClickHandler"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is My BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void headerClickHandler(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnBack:
            Toast.makeText(this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

this is my activity:

```
public class PersonnelInfo extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_personnel_info);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.personnel_info, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you call setcontentview for this layout in this activity?

Comment: @zohreh Where should I setcontentview for this layout?

Comment: where you set this layout to your activity?

Comment: you should override oncreate method for your activity and setcontentview in it

Comment: The problem is that I can't override onCreate in Base activity because it has conflicts with derive activity.

Comment: are you using Header.xml layout in derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:onClick="headerClickHandler"` from xml

In base activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public OnClickListener headerClickHandler = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnBack:
                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

In derive activity:

```
Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
btnBack.setOnClickListener(headerClickHandler);
```

Comment: It produce a syntax error here: public OnClickListener headerClickHandler;
I don't know why it causes a syntax error says: "Syntax error on token ";", , expected"

Comment: I don't understand why!

Comment: Almost done! a small problem is that in the command: 
Toast.makeText(this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
'this' refers to OnClickListener, how to refer to the current activity?

Comment: Replace `this` by `BaseActivity.this`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you forgot to extends from your BaseActivity

`public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity`

I tried and everything is Ok

MainActivity

```
package com.stackoverflow.reusableview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

BaseActivity

```
package com.stackoverflow.reusableview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
public void headerClickHandler(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnBack:
        Toast.makeText(this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/txtHeading"
    android:text="@string/general_title"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:text="@string/return_value"
    android:onClick="headerClickHandler"
    />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<include layout="@layout/header"/>
```